# XHTML/HTML/JS syntax: When do I use &amp;? 

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities, web-standards, standards-compliance

I am confused when I should use & and when I should use `&amp;`, specifically when it's inside Javascript inside HTML.

Which (or both or neither) of these two URLs should use html-encoding?

```
<!-- Example 1 -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var myUrl = "myurl.html?bob=2&mary=3"; // or is it &amp;?
    downloadUrl(myUrl);
</script>

<!-- Example 2 -->
<p>Click <a href="myurl.html?bob=2&mary=3">here</a> <!-- &amp;? --> if the download doesn't start.</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, you *should* use `&amp;` instead of `&`. In XHTML/XML, you **must** use `&amp;` instead of `&`. This also applies to inline JavaScript code. This doesn't apply to JavaScript code served by fullworthy `.js` files unless the text becomes part of the HTML DOM tree.

Comment: I'm not sure about inline JS code, check http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/script/#script-best-practice

Comment: @rober: Inside a XML `CDATA` block you indeed don't need to escape XML entities. Outside it, you **must** escape them. However, I consider putting JS code in its own `.js` file a better practice than those ugly `CDATA` blocks.

Answer (score -1):

In the first example it should be `&`. In the second it should be `&amp;`

Comment: I believe this is incorrect, and definitely conflicts with @BalusC.  Putting it inside a <script> doesn't seem to magically allow non-encoded entities.